# How to distinguish .msi and office files by java?

Tags: java, windows-installer

I want to get the real ext of office files, but .msi has the same header as office 2003-2007 files. How can I distinguish .msi and office files by java?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Both old office format and .msi files use [Structured Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage) as the container format. You have to analyze the individual streams to distinguish the actual formats. For instance, the summary information stream of a .msi file contains the property "Title" with a value of "Installation Database". I can't tell you how to read structured storage with Java though.